# Checking to see if DropDownList selected index has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my C# web application, I have three textboxes, three drop down lists, and one button.

The button is suppose to run a SQL string that will take the values of whatever is in typed in the textboxes, whatever is selected, and be inserted into the database. The values inserted may not be null so I don't want any blank entries. By default, I have the DropDownList like so in the source:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ReadDrop" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So there is a blank entry (default), and then the yes/no. There are three of these drop down lists in the application. In my C# code, I have the following to prevent the button from firing if there is a blank entry:

```
if (UsernameBox.Text != "" & FirstNameBox.Text != "" & LastNameBox.Text != "" /* check for blank dropdownlist? */)
```

My current issue is that I don't know how to check the dropdownlist for a blank entry. My guess would have been to check to see if ReadDrop.Text is blank, but I am relatively inexperienced in ASP.NET and am wondering if there is a "proper" way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: ReadDrop.selectedValue I think but it's been a while since I wrote any C#, you should be able to check the selectedValue for null or ""

Comment: show your full c#  code?

Comment: why first listitem is blank?

Comment: What is the point of me showing my full C# code? I showed the part that is relevant and it is informative enough. I have it as such because you ideally want the user to make their selection and not have it already made to prevent, "Oh, I see I already filled that part in." when they didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`SelectedIndex > 0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (UsernameBox.Text != "" & FirstNameBox.Text != "" & LastNameBox.Text != "" && ReadDrop.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that the `SelectedIndex` is -1 if no item is selected and yes/no have 1/2.

Another option is to use the [`SelectedItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ListItem selectedItem = ReadDrop.SelectedItem;
if(selectedItem != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedItem.Text))
{
  // ...
}
```

However, i think that you actually want to prevent that the user selects no item,  or in other words, validate that he selects something. Then use a `RequiredFieldValidator`, you have to set the `InitialValue` to `""`:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Select Something" ControlToValidate="ReadDrop" 
    InitialValue=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

You could assign a different `Value` to your empty item and change the `InitialValue` appropriately:

Comment: @Leon: if you want to ensure that the user selected something use a `RequiredFieldValidator`. I have shown an example.

Comment: That's very interesting. I have six fields, would I need to create six distinct  `RequiredFieldValidator`?

Comment: @Leon: yes, that's the best way, one validator for one control. There is another option, you could use a `CustomValidator` which handles all controls. But i normally prefer the one validator for one control approach if the validation rules are not so complex. Then you have one meaningful error-message for every control. You could also use a ASP.NET-Ajax [`ValidatorCalloutExtender`](http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-validatorcallout-extender-asp-net-c/) control to beautify validation.

Comment: I see `RequiredFieldValidation` in Visual Studio so I'm going to play around with it. Thank you for the insightful comment.

Comment: I actually have a follow up question if you're available. I have two buttons, "Confirm" and "Cancel". I'm currently using `RequiredFieldValidation`, and it works very well. However, if I click the "Cancel" button, it will set off the error message when ideally I just want the "Cancel" button to post back to another page. Is there a way to prevent the messages from firing for the "Cancel" button?